# What does child mean in an android layout?

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development, so what is meant by child in the below paragraph....

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in
>   it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be
>   a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is
>   often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a
>   vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Please go through the basic tutorials of android. This place is for problems you face during development.

Comment: Dear gaurav dont panic, just add linear layout in scrollview and other stuff in linear.. Scrollview support only single child-means one layout or whatever..widget you decalre

Answer (score 3):

In android (and most other technologies), views can have subviews, aka "children". Most views can have children and can be a child of a parent view. It's kind of like a "tree".

The most obvious feature of being a child of some other view is that the child moves with the parent view. Another feature is that the child is in the coordinate space of the parent view.

Your paragraph here basically says you can only put one child view in `ScrollView` and it is usually a `LinearLayout`. But don't be fooled! This child can have its own child views.

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav i think this is what you looking for, you need to use ***only one*** **LinearLayout** tag inside **ScrollView** tag, if you are using more than one **LinearLayout** than it will show *error*. If you want to use *more* **LinearLayout** tag you can use them inside **LinearLayout** tag which is inside **ScrollView** tag. May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the general concept of child and parent . Simply you can think of the real life relation between parent and child.on the hierarchy parents are toplevel and child is below.so when you come to android layout parent is container and child is the content.